# How can i properly cast this object from list?

Tags: c#

I have a method as such:

```
public static document[] search(document type, searchword[] searchwords) {}
```

My problem is here :

```
List<searchword> filledwords = new List<searchword>();
```

I populate in a loop as such : `filledwords.Add(term);`

Now when i try to call the search method:

```
search(type,  (searchword[])filledwords)
```

I am having casting errors, I even did some trial and errors like :

```
 search(type,  (searchword[])filledwords[0]) but no success.
```

This is because i am converting a Java project into C# and this is my first month with c#.

Here is the Java Equivalent which works :

```
List filledwords= new ArrayList();
filledwords.add(term);
search(type,(SearchTerm[])filledwords.toArray(new SearchTerm[0]))
```

Any guide i appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add these casting errors to your question

Comment: .Net's Generic list also has the ToArray() method. Why did you omit that while porting to C#? Just call search(type,  filledwords.ToArray())

Comment: `filledwords.ToArray()`... Anyway include the actual error and your research for it in your question.

Comment: What is the difference between `searchword` and `SearchTerm`? Your method takes an array of `searchword`, but you try to cast it to an array of `SearchTerm`.

Comment: `filledwords.ToArray()` will through the exception since `SearchTerm` and `searchword` are different.

Comment: Markus sorry refractor mistake.

Comment: `search` is too *brittle* (it wants arrays only), and so you have that pesky errors; think on re-design `search` into something like `search<T>(IEnumerable<T> filledwords)`

Comment: @Irshad refractor mistake, it all searchword or searchterm, this was just to avoid real code here

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - I was just about to make the same suggestion!

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions - and also, I'd recommend that you avoid raw types in Java, too...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for the great tip !

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the advice. I will move towards that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ToArray` method to convert the list to an array:

```
search(type,  filledwords.ToArray());
```

An alternative is to change the signature of the `search` method to receive an `IEnumerable<searchword>` if you only want to iterate over the search words:

```
public static document[] search(document type, IEnumerable<searchword> searchwords) {}
```

Then you don't need to cast at all:

```
search(type,  filledwords);
```

Comment: Use IList<searchword> instead. That should do. (Array<T> implicitly implements the IList<T> Interface). Or alternativly use .ElementAt() or ElementAtOrDefault() extensionmethods.